# Code throws SEVERE: No value specified for parameter 1 excetion

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to find a list of items from my database but it throws an exception. My code and error are as following , all field types are correct.

**Code**

```
     System.out.println("2");
      try {
           ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Users Where name = ?);"

        ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();
        ps.setString(1, "jack");
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        ....
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
```

**Output**

```
INFO: 2
SEVERE: No value specified for parameter 1
INFO: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6520c5b
```

Comment: Would have been easy to find the error just looking at the line where the exception has raised!

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie do not know where the line is

Comment: As Luiggi answered, I'm pretty sure the exception is raised on this line : ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();` before setting the parameters on your `PreparedStatement`. Probably a typo when coding this method since you have a similar line below setting the parameters on your `PreparedStatement`.

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(...);
//comment this line
// ResultSet r = ps.executeQuery();
ps.setString(1, "1");
//...
ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
```

Not directly related with your question, it would be better if you use a logger instead of plain `System.out.println` calls in your code. It will help you to maintain your code by providing better messages to your logs.

Comment: would please you give me an example for logger

Comment: @JackRamzi that's outside the question scope. Also, instead of just using any logger at all, check what logger implementation is used in your application server (since the question was tagged as Java EE first) and see in that app server forums about how to use the logger in your app.